# Meteor upsert with mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, upsert

I need to use upsert because something a record in my Accounts schema (see below) may not exist. The defining factors for its existence are adviserID and period. If a record that matches both of those exists it should just update the record.

However when I run this, I get this error: Sanitized and reported to the client as: Adviser id must be an object [400]. When I console.log(adviser) inside the updateOrder method it does indeed report correctly the adviser ObjectID.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Upsert method:

```
Meteor.methods({
  updateOrder: function(adviser, order, period) {
    Account.upsert(
    {
      adviserId: adviser,
      period: period
    }, {
      $set: {
        adviserId: adviser,
        order: order,
        outstanding: order,
        period: period
      }
   });
  }
});
```

Schema:

```
Schema.Account = new SimpleSchema({
  "adviserId": {
    type: Object,
  },
  period: {
    type: Date,
    label: "Order Period"
  },
  order: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    label: "Order Number"
  },
  outstanding: {
    type: Number,
    min: 0,
    defaultValue: 0,
    label: "Outstanding Number"
  }
});
```

Comment: What is "adviser" in the method? Is it a id (string) or some object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From SimpleSchema Docs:

> If you have a key with type Object, the properties of the object will be validated as well, so you must define all allowed properties in the schema.

`adviser` in your method should be a string because you use it for the find (in upsert). If your `adviser` is a string, then just fix your schema for `{type: String, regEx: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id}`. Or if you want to use an object, then you need describe it or add [blackbox option](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-simple-schema#blackbox).

Comment: Hi, I think you're definitely on the right track. Unfortunately, just blackboxing the object doesn't seem to stop any validation so always says adviserId should be an object.

Comment: @user1496093 if "blackbox" doesn't help, then that is not an object. I think it's a string, try to use "type: String"

Comment: Hi. When I console..log(adviser) which should be the adviserId coming from this._id it returns ObjectID("56cdc8be14c6ddae95becfdd"). I have used blackbox on the adviserId schema and it still rejects it saying that AdviserId must be an object. Kinda stumped.

Comment: @user1496093 Could you show how you send data in the method (call it). Because for the similar example in my case I get something like `Fs2SRhd2eAfrQyvDE`

Answer (score 1):

More than likely you want adviserId to be a string.  MongoDB internal ID objects are strings in Meteor.

Comment: Hi wrapping adviser like so String(adviser) didn't work. Any ideas? adviser is this according to console M…D.ObjectID {_str: "56c7344d685029e7aa325f7b"}

Comment: Is that _str equal to the adviser Id you want?

Answer (score 1):

This is how we upsert in meteor.

```
 Shares.update({
                 adviserId: adviser,
                 period: period
              }, {
                 $set: {
                    adviserId: adviser,
                    order: order,
                    outstanding: order,
                    period: period
                 }
              }, {
                  upsert: true
              })
```

Comment: Thank you but this is still not working:   updateOrder: function(adviser, order, period) {
    console.log(adviser);

    Account.update(
    {
      adviserId: String(adviser),
      period: period,
    }, {
      $set: {
        adviserId: String(adviser),
        order: order,
        outstanding: order,
        period: period
      }
    }, {upsert: true});
  }

Comment: It will be great if you can share the minimal code with me, I will look at that.

Comment: I didn't get anything from the jsfiddle. You can share it on github with minimal code.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Bryukhanov Valentin. Converting to type String resolved my issues.

Thanks also to those that replied.